# Sum of part of a column in a join statement

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

**SteelOrders**

```
OrderNumber
-----------
0000843989    
0000843124    
0000881234    
0000123456    
-----------
```

**FinalizedPrintedStickers**

```
SN                  |  PanelBuildTime
-------------------------------------
0000843989-8R8-4-0  |  360
0000843989-8R8-4-1  |  200
0000843989-8R8-4-2  |  900    
0000843989-8R8-4-3  |  360
0000843989-8R8-4-4  |  460
0000843989-8S-1-0   |  220    
0000843989-8-2-0    |  360
etc..
-------------------------------------
```

The desired **result** would be:

```
OrderNumber |  PanelBuildTime
-----------------------------
0000843989  |  2860    
etc..
-----------------------------
```

**What have I tried?**

```
Select OrderNumber, Sum(PanelBuildTime) from SteelOrders 
INNER JOIN FinalizedPrintedStickers 
ON 
SteelOrders.OrderNumber = LEFT(FinalizedPrintedStickers.SN,10)
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how to add a `WHERE` clause on to this per item in the steelorder table

Also (Since I'm using oledb in my C# code to read from the steel order table) I've tried for every read of the `OleDbDataReader` Executing the `Select Sum(PanelBuildtime) where ordernumber = reader["OrderNumber"]`, but that's extremely slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by the order number to show the summary of the build times

```
Select OrderNumber, Sum(PanelBuildTime) from SteelOrders 
INNER JOIN FinalizedPrintedStickers 
ON 
SteelOrders.OrderNumber = LEFT(FinalizedPrintedStickers.SN,10)
GROUP BY SteelOrders.OrderNumber
```

Comment: Ahh, You've included a string literal, There's thousands of orders, They all need sumations of build times, this sum's one

Comment: so you want a group by then which shows the sum of build times for each order number.  I have changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because you often might want to different columns with different conditions, you should also know about the `case` statement:

```
Select OrderNumber, Sum(case when SteelOrders.item = '0000843989' then PanelBuildTime end)
from SteelOrders INNER JOIN
    FinalizedPrintedStickers 
    ON SteelOrders.OrderNumber = LEFT(FinalizedPrintedStickers.SN,10)
```

In Access (sorry, I missed the tag), you have to use `IIF` instead of `case`.

Oh, based on your comment above, you want a `group by`:

```
Select OrderNumber, Sum(PanelBuildTime)
from SteelOrders INNER JOIN
    FinalizedPrintedStickers 
    ON SteelOrders.OrderNumber = LEFT(FinalizedPrintedStickers.SN,10)
group by OrderNumber
```

Comment: You can't use a case statement with Access.