# Where clause In Sum statement using group by

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables 1 is called **SteelOrders** the other is called **FinalizedPrintedStickers**

and i recently just asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879917/sum-of-part-of-a-column-in-a-join-statement) question.

Although I got an answer, I left out a few huge details in the question that have lead me to this question.

I currently have this query:

```
Select OrderNumber,  Sum(PanelBuildTime)  AS OrderBuildTime from SteelOrders 
INNER JOIN FinalizedPrintedStickers 
ON 
SteelOrders.OrderNumber = LEFT(FinalizedPrintedStickers.SN,10)
GROUP BY OrderNumber
```

I need to get the Sum of PanelBuildTime From FinalizedPrintedStickers, But only where the 'Status' Field in the FinalizedPrintedStickers table is = 'Printed'

How do i add a where clause to the Sum statement?

Any help would be greatly appreciated ^_^

**Edit:** If There's no statuses = 'Printed' on the FinalizedPrintedStickers table I need the 'OrderBuildTime'  to be 0 .... I don't know if this is actually possible using Access or not, Hopefully it is..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your reply to Beth, I think you want an `IIf()` expression in your select list:

```
Sum(IIF([Status] = 'Printed', PanelBuildTime, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need?

just read your other question with the scema details, sry.  How about:

```
    Select OrderNumber,  
      Sum(case when PanelBuildTime is null then 0 else PanelBuildTime end)  AS OrderBuildTime 
    from SteelOrders 
    left outer JOIN (select * from FinalizedPrintedStickers  
       where Status = 'Printed') f ON 
    SteelOrders.OrderNumber = LEFT(FinalizedPrintedStickers.SN,10)
    GROUP BY OrderNumber
```

or

```
Select OrderNumber,  
  Sum(statusPrintedCount )  AS OrderBuildTime 
from SteelOrders 
inner JOIN (select *, 
case when Status = 'Printed' then 1 else 0 end as statusPrintedCount 
   from FinalizedPrintedStickers) f ON 
SteelOrders.OrderNumber = LEFT(FinalizedPrintedStickers.SN,10)
GROUP BY OrderNumber
```

sry, missed the access tag.  this is for SQL Server.

Comment: No, because i need all of the rows of the Main table (SteelOrders) , this will just give me rows where the status is printed, I need it so that if there's no statuses as printed in the order it shows the orderbuildtime as 0. Sorry about my unclear question, i couldn't think of how to word it =/

Comment: `case ... when` is not supported in Access SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
Select Distinct a.*, b.PanelBuildTime
From SteelOrders a, 
(Select OrderNumber,  Sum(PanelBuildTime)  AS OrderBuildTime from SteelOrders 
INNER JOIN FinalizedPrintedStickers 
ON 
SteelOrders.OrderNumber = LEFT(FinalizedPrintedStickers.SN,10)
GROUP BY OrderNumber) b
Where a.OrderNumber = b.OrderNumber
```

EDIT: You just edited your initial post and it changes things. You already got your answer so its ok I guess ;)